# The TOC functionality on TFS wiki doesn't work

Tags: tfs, wiki, tableofcontents

I want to get the TOC at the top of the page.
I am using the code suggested by TFS wiki for markdown, which is:
[[*TOC*]]
But it doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What have you attempted so far with your implementation to the solution? What error messages have you recieved (if any)? You need to edit your question with details so that people can attempt to help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The TOC feature was released 08/21/2018, see [Create table of contents for wiki pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/aug-21-vsts#create-table-of-contents-for-wiki-pages). Your hosted TFS Server is likely behind that release.